# OmniAuth connection failed with facebook callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I'm using the OmniAuth GEM and have successfully got it working with the twitter strategy. I am now trying to set up the ability for users to also use there facebook login.

I got it to the point where it correct redirected me to facebook. I confirmed access on the facebook site and got redirected back to my callback url (the default auth/facebook/callback) but here it errors.

I have the same routes as for twitter

```
  match "auth/facebook/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "auth/twitter/callback" => "sessions#create"
```

but I am getting a error

> Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
>   state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

The one thing I find very wrong is the session dump is showing this (having replaced some keys with XXX/ABC)

> _csrf_token: "ABC/ABC=" oauth: {"twitter"=>{"callback_confirmed"=>true,
>   "request_token"=>"XXX",
>   "request_secret"=>"XXX"}}
>   session_id: "XXX"

It is mentioning twitter in here, but I tried to login with facebook. Maybe something to do with the fact I was logged in with twitter before signing out and trying to log in with facebook. but I doubt it and think this is something to do with the reason its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use below routes instead of yours

```
match "auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
```

and change your facebook settings as

AccountSettings => security => Secure Browsing => Disabled

as attached in screen shot.[image]

So Local just disable and in production buy a SSL certificate it will works.

Comment: I cannot see those settings, is it a old screenshot? I am looking at, I am currently going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ABC/summary but don't see "Secure Browsing" option anywhere

Comment: This is not developers.facebook.com just go to facebook.com and change. So by using your current development application who disabiled secure browing those people only able to access the app. but in production you need to buy the SSL for your APP.

Comment: right so my app HAS to connect with SSL? thats a pain if thats the case. Also session dump is still saying twitter. I've even put facebook as the first provider.

Comment: have you replaced the routes with **match "auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"** it is saying twitter because route has been replaced by latest.

Comment: Can you check this solution [https://gist.github.com/vargeorge/3768187](https://gist.github.com/vargeorge/3768187)